# Gridlines Between Pixels on HTML5 <canvas> Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, pixel

I am working on a simple pixel art program just as a fun project while learning JS.
I want to have each pixel on the canvas be surrounded by a 1px border.
My only idea is to create a overlaying grid and size it to fit the canvas pixels.
such as:

```html
<div 
  class="grid" 
  style="width: (canvas width); height: (canvas height); background-image: (transparent image with 1px border); background-size: (size of each canvas pixel); pointer-events: none;"
></div>
<br>
```

and position it over the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use many in memory canvases as layers

The easiest way is to keep the drawing on a separate canvas. Use the main canvas only as a final display.

Once you have the drawing separate from the display canvas you can start to layer visual FX .

### To copy an image (canvas, jpeg, png, etc...)

To outline a pixel art image create a draw-able copy of the image.

```
function copyImage(image){
    const copy = document.createElement("canvas");
    copy.width = image.width;
    copy.height = image.height;
    copy.ctx = copy.getContext("2d");
    copy.ctx.drawImage(image);
    return copy;
}
```

To create a blank canvas layer

```
function createImage(w, h){
    const img = document.createElement("canvas");
    img.width = w;
    img.height = h;
    img.ctx = img.getContext("2d");
    return img;
}
```

### Outline layer

Draw that copy over its self 1 pixel to the left, 1 to the right, 1 above and 1 below. Then set the out line color

```
function outlineLayer(image, color) {
    const ctx = image.ctx;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.drawImage(image, -1,  0);
    ctx.drawImage(image,  1,  0);
    ctx.drawImage(image,  0, -1);
    ctx.drawImage(image,  0,  1);

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, image.width, image.height);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
```

### Rendering

When you render the image you first draw the outline layer before image.

Using the functions above

```
// ctx is the context of the visual (on page) canvas
// myArt is a drawing. It is a canvas that is kept in memory and not on the page.
const outline = copyImage(myArt);
outlineLayer(outline, "black");

// then draw both on the main canvas
// First outline
ctx.drawImage(outline, 0, 0);
// then the pixels
ctx.drawImage(myArt, 0, 0);
```

### Collapse layers

You can also collapse the layers making the outline permanent

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
myArt.ctx.drawImage(outline, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // restore default
```

Comment: does that allow me to still draw on the canvas with the cursor? The main canvas needs to be the one saving the image because The user can draw on it, I may very well be wrong but I think using a overlay might be easier for this purpose :p

Comment: I guess I could have the pointer action draw on the memory canvas and then immediatly copy over to the display one

Comment: @finnb Yes you set up an animation loop using`requestAnimationFrame` to copy to display only when needed You can have hundreds of layers on the average laptop before it starts to bog down

Answer (score -1):

If you want a border/outline around your Canvas, try this:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want, I have a border around my canvas, I want a border around each pixel